# How do I load only the specified columns and still get a model object? (without defer)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to:

1. Load only the fields I want, from multiple tables/models.
2. Get back "model objects", not the namedtuple-like objects I would from get passing the columns to `session.query`. This should span relationships, so for instance `employee.company.name`, where company is a relationship field in the Employee model.
3. Prevent other fields from being inadvertently loaded after the initial select query. I could use `defer` or `.load_only('field_name')` but then someone else could access an attribute of the model I didn't specify and that would cause another query to run. Ideally, accessing a field that wasn't specified in the query would raise an `AttributeError`, even if that field is defined in the model.

Is this possible using mechanisms provided by SqlAlchemy? Would this even be a good idea?

I wrote the following function that does what I want, but it seems someone else must've met these needs in a better and more standard way.

```
class Attributable(object):
    pass


def spread_result(row, columns):
    """
        :type row: sqlalchemy.util._collections.KeyedTuple
        :type columns: tuple
        Usage:
        >>> result = session.query(Model.field, AnotherModel.other_field).first()
        >>> obj = spread_result(result, ('field', 'another_model.other_field'))
        >>> obj.field
        'field_value'
        >>> obj.another_model.other_field
        'other_field_value'
        >>> obj.another_mapped_field
        AttributeError: 'Attributable' object has no attribute 'another_mapped_field'
    """
    root = Attributable()
    for column, value in zip(columns, row):
        obj = root
        parts = column.split('.')
        for i, attr in enumerate(parts):
            if i == len(parts) - 1:
                setattr(obj, attr, value)
            else:
                setattr(obj, attr, Attributable())
                obj = getattr(obj, attr)

    return root
```

Comment: you're definitely using load_only(), as far as the "private" access, it's not typically the "python" way, but you could build a `__getattribute__()` method on your object that achieves this, by checking in `self.__dict__` for the specified key, and if not exists, throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create a "public" model that maps to the same table but only contains the columns and other properties that you want loadable/accessible.

The [relevant documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapper_config.html#mapping-a-subset-of-table-columns) says:

> the include_properties or exclude_properties arguments can specify that only a subset of columns should be mapped

If you have a Person model which users should just see id and name from, the "public" class would look like this:

```
class PublicPerson(Base):
    __table__ = Person.__table__

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'include_properties': ['id', 'name']
    }
```

Here is a simple runnable example:

```
from datetime import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
session = Session(bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)


class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    birthday = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)


class PublicPerson(Base):
    __table__ = Person.__table__

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'include_properties': ['id', 'name']
    }


Base.metadata.create_all()

session.add(Person(name='Jan', birthday=datetime(2001, 1, 1)))

# query the full person, prints birthday
print(session.query(Person.birthday).scalar())

# query the "public" person, raises exception on birthday
print(session.query(PublicPerson.birthday).scalar())
```